# What should I do when 'svn cleanup' fails?

Tags: svn

I have a lot of changes in a working folder, and something screwed up trying to do an update.

Now when I issue an 'svn cleanup' I get:

```
>svn cleanup .
svn: In directory '.'
svn: Error processing command 'modify-wcprop' in '.'
svn: 'MemPoolTests.cpp' is not under version control
```

MemPoolTests.cpp is a new file another developer added and was brought down in the update. It did not exist in my working folder before.

Is there anything I can do to try and move forward **without** having to checkout a fresh copy of the repository?

**Clarification:** Thanks for the suggestions about moving the directory out of the way and bringing down a new copy. I know that is an option, but it is one I'd like to avoid since there are many changes nested several directories deep (this should have been a branch...)

I'm hoping for a more aggressive way of doing the cleanup, maybe someway of forcing the file SVN is having trouble with back into a known state (and I tried deleting the working copy of it ... that didn't help).

Comment: Re: Using a new copy. Grab a copy of beyond compare to diff the versions against each other

Comment: Did amin's solution not work for you? Surely an obvious answer to accept otherwise?

Comment: Make sure any of the files are not kept open by an application, it's easy to forget. Process Explorer and a quick search on the path is very useful to uncover this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: IMHO the existence of the "svn cleanup" command is an admission of failure.

Comment: Did you see this one: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128598/svn-code-cleanup-issue

Comment: For older versions of svn one might need to delete `.svn/log` in that directory as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387736/svn-cleanup-causes-error-processing-command-modify-wcprop .

Comment: 31 answers but none accepted. Learning point: commit often. Don't make too many complicated changes without a commit. Not only because svn might get confused. Also because you might get confused and might want to revert some of your complicated changes by rolling back to a previous commit. If you cannot continue with a new, fresh, checkout, your workflow is sub-optimal. So don't fight svn, but utilize it to the full.

Answer (score 229):

When starting all over is not an option...

I deleted the log file in the `.svn` directory (I also deleted the offending file in `.svn/props-base`), did a cleanup, and resumed my update.

Comment: I was getting a similar problem to the original question here (due to an interrupted svn checkout). This fixed it for me. Though I also had to go up to the parent directory and do the same there.

Comment: Fixed an interrupted svn commit for me.

Comment: +1 I cant tell you how many times I have been in this situation. When it is a sub-sub folder no problem, just delete the whole folder, cleanup and update. But when it is a file in the root level this is not a cheap option (several hours to checkout the whole project again). Fantastic Tip - many thanks.

Comment: I just needed to delete all the log files. A million thanks to you!  You saved me from having to re-download 100gb+ from our repo.

Comment: For me the deleting of the lock files did it. Maybe of interest for somebody. You can delete them recursively with the following command: rm -rf `find . -type f -name lock`

Comment: It works but can you explain why deleting log files fixs the problem?

Comment: Another option.  The top rated response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290734/unlocking-svn-working-copy-with-unversioned-resources

Comment: I'm confused because in SVN 1.7, I see /.svn/ has only /pristine/, /tmp/, and files entries, format, db, wc.db?

Comment: happy-coding's command doesn't work. This does: `sudo rm -rf | find . -type f -name lock`

Comment: Or just `find . -type f -name lock -delete`

Comment: http://www.anujvarma.com/svn-cleanup-failedprevious-operation-has-not-finished-run-cleanup-if-it-was-interrupted/ 

This was quite helpful

Comment: It also worked for me in a case where deleting the whole folder and checking out again didn't. I am using TortoiseSVN on Windows7 and had an issue with lowercase/uppercase foldernames which were equal in windows...

Comment: I could not find `.svn/prop-base` I have `.svn/[pristine|tmp|entries|format|wc.db]`

Comment: Another option that worked for me was doing the clean up at the parent folder of the certain directory

Answer (score 124):

Things have changed with SVN 1.7, and the popular solution of deleting the log file in the .svn directory isn't feasible with the move to a database working-copy implementation.

Here's what I did that seemed to work:

1. Delete the .svn directory for your working copy.
2. Start a new checkout in a new, temporary directory.
3. Cancel the checkout (we don't want to wait for everything to get pulled down).
4. Run a cleanup on this cancelled checkout.
5. Now we have a new .svn directory with a clean database (although no/few files)
6. Copy this .svn into your old, corrupted working directory.
7. Run svn update and it should bring your new partial .svn directory up to speed with your old working directory.

That's all a little confusing, process wise. Essentially, what we're doing is deleting the corrupt .svn then creating a new .svn for the same checkout path. We then move this new .svn to our old working directory and update it to the repo.

I just did this in TSVN and it seems to work fine and not require a full checkout and download.

-Jody

Comment: I seem do this at least twice a month. Such a pain. The svn team should add theses steps `svn cleanup --force`. And of course all add, delete and (with 1.8) rename operations are lost.

Comment: @Adgezaza Yes. Yes it does.

Comment: this fix it for me. It's a little different: after changing svn, update fail for 1 specific folder. Delete that folder and everything is fine

Comment: @Pup, it should. Essentially you're just pulling down the metadata for a new checkout and then populating it with files. SVN will determine if the files match the metadata or not.

But, you know, zip everything up first just in case...

Comment: I reinstalled the SVN (Tortoise SVN 1.8), reveved every ,svn folder from my project, then performed operations mentioned here and voila! Thanks to author!

Comment: @Pup it did for me :)

Comment: in step 6, should I remove the old stuff from the corrupt .svn or just dump the new files in and overwriting the matching ?

Comment: @user230910, the .svn is a special folder that shouldn't have any of your actual source files in it. You deleted the .svn in the corrupt checkout (step 1) so copying in a new .svn shouldn't be overwriting anything.

Comment: Simply format your computer and start anew. Another option is migrating all your infrastructure to git, it's gonna take less time than repair your SVN repo.

Answer (score 119):

Take a look at

http://www.anujvarma.com/svn-cleanup-failedprevious-operation-has-not-finished-run-cleanup-if-it-was-interrupted/

Summary of fix from above link (Thanks to Anuj Varma)

> 1. Install sqlite command-line shell (sqlite-tools-win32) from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
> 2. `sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "select * from work_queue"`
>
> The SELECT should show you your offending folder/file as part of the
>   work queue. What you need to do is delete this item from the work
>   queue.
>
> 3. `sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "delete from work_queue"`
>
> That’s it. Now, you can run cleanup again – and it should work. Or you
>   can proceed directly to the task you were doing before being prompted
>   to run cleanup (adding a new file etc.)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Firefox has [sqlite manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) extension that can open and edit the .svn/wc.db file.  Provides a convenient GUI to do equivalent operations on work_queue.

Comment: If you have a recent version of SVN and Firefox, the sqlite manager addon takes care of this issue in 30 seconds. Don't worry about deleting directories or using the Repobrowser.  In 2016 I think this should be the accepted answer

Comment: For me running 'delete from WC_LOCK;' is required as well.

Comment: Work perfectly ! Svn sucks ! But after delete from work_queue svn give me an other error "svn locked", just run with tortoise ( eclipse don't have the option ) clean up with "break locks" checked

Answer (score 42):

If all else fails:

1. Check out into a new folder.
2. Copy your modified files over.
3. Check back in.
4. Zip the old folder up somewhere (you never know + paranoia is good) before deleting it and using the new one.

Answer (score 29):

The latest verion (I'm using 1.9.5) solve this problem by adding an option of "Break locks" on the clean up menu. Just make sure this check box is selected when doing clean up.

[image: eclean up window]

Comment: It seems so obvious now! Thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Works well for me.

Comment: Worked! When I saw this solution I immediately knew what the problem was ... (I think): I had an excel still open, which modifies it. I wanted to commit my changes to some java files and saw the excel file and was like "I didn't change anythere there ... revert". Which did not work, then I realised it's still open, closed it, F5, didn't appear in commit anmore, so proceed to commit. And then it tells me "pls run cleanup" and from there on I was stuck. So Thanks! :)

Answer (score 16):

*This answer only applies to versions before 1.7 (thanks @ŁukaszBachman)*.

Subversion stores its information per folder (in .svn), so if you are just dealing with a subfolder you don't need checkout the whole repository - just the folder that has borked:

```
cd dir_above_borked
mv borked_dir borked_dir.bak
svn update borked_dir
```

This will give you a good working copy of the borked folder, but you still have your changes backed up in borked_dir.bak. The same principle applies with Windows/TortoiseSVN.

If you have changes in an isolated folder have a look at the

```
svn checkout -N borked_dir   # Non-recursive, but deprecated
```

or

```
svn checkout --depth=files borked_dir
# 'depth' is new territory to me, but do 'svn help checkout'
```

Comment: saved huge amount of time using your suggestion "if you are just dealing with a subfolder you don't need checkout the whole repository"

Comment: This worked for me - all I did was `svn up` the same repo that was in the middle of an `svn up` in a different tab - I forgot I had done that and left it incomplete the night before.

Comment: No longer true - with newest version SVN is now using just one `.svn` directory.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ ls -la .svn
$ rm -f .svn/lock
```

Then

```
$ svn update
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem. I couldn't commit, and cleanup would fail.

Using a command-line client I was able to see an error message indicating that it was failing to move a file from `.svn/props` to `.svn/prop-base`.

I looked at the specific file and found that it was marked read-only. After removing the read-only attribute I was able to cleanup the folder and the commit my changes.

Comment: I gave up on that tree, and got a new one in the end.  But thanks for the hint on something to check next time.

Comment: ha...i even renamed the folders in the .svn\pristine area from {name} to {name}_old and then back to the original {name} and it worked

Answer (score 6):

It's possible that you have a problem with two filenames differing only by uppercase. If you ran into this problem, creating another working copy directory does not solve the problem.

Current Windows (i.e. crappy) filesystems simply do not grok the difference between `Filename` and `FILEname`. You have two possible fixes:

1. Check out at platform with a real filesystem (Unix-based), rename the file, and commit changes.
2. When you are bound to Windows you can rename files in the Eclipse SVN repository browser which does recognise the difference and rename the file there.
3. You can rename the problematic files also remotely from any command-line SVN client using `svn rename -m "broken filename case" http://server/repo/FILEname http://server/repo/filename`

Comment: This turned out to be my problem; a coworker had somehow managed to check in several Xcode project files, each with two copies differing only be letter case. I used TortoiseSVN to browse the repo and delete the extra files. Then I deleted my local folders containing the duplicate files, and svn update finally succeeded.

Comment: Not merely a Windows issue. This also affects Macs too. Macs HFS+ filesystems, by default, also does case-insensitive, but case preserving file names. I've setup a second partition on my hard drive that does case-sensitive file names in order to get around these issues.

Answer (score 6):

I've tried to do `svn cleanup` via the console and got an error like:

```
svn: E720002: Can't open file '..\.svn\pristine\40\40d53d69871f4ff622a3fbb939b6a79932dc7cd4.svn-base':
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So I created this file manually (empty) and did `svn cleanup` again. This time it was done OK.

Answer (score 4):

Run `svn cleanup` command in a terminal (if it fails from Eclipse which was my case):

```
~/path/to/svn-folder/$ svn cleanup
```

---

**I tried different solutions** explained here, but **none worked**.

Action *Team* → *Update to head* fails:

> svn: E155004: There are unfinished work items in '/home/user/path/to/svn-folder'; run 'svn cleanup' first.

Action *Team* → *Cleanup* fails with same error.

Solution that worked for me: **run *svn cleanup* command in a terminal**.

The command succeeded.

Then *Team* → *Update* in Eclipse worked again.

Note: my SVN version is 1.9.3.

Also check [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4402137/912046) if `svn cleanup` does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. For me the cause was a conflict with EasySVN and (TortoiseSVN or just SVN). I had auto update and commit with EasySVN (which wasn't working).

When I turned this off, I was unable to cleanup, commit, or update. None of the above solutions worked, but rebooting did :)

Comment: Yaaaaay jimi, you are my hero(in).

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is case sensitivity (which can be a problem when checking out to a Mac, as well as Windows) and you don't have the option of checking out onto a *nix system, the following should work. Here's the process from the beginning:

```
% svn co http://[domain]/svn/mortgages mortgages
```

(Checkout ensues… then…)

```
svn: In directory 'mortgages/trunk/images/rates'
svn: Can't open file 'mortgages/trunk/images/rates/.svn/tmp/text-base/Header_3_nobookmark.gif.svn-base': No such file or directory
```

Here SVN is trying to check out two files with similar names that differ only by case - `Header_3_noBookmark.gif` and `Header_3_nobookmark.gif`. Mac filesystems default to case insensitivity in a way that causes SVN to choke in situations like this. So...

```
% cd mortgages/trunk/images/rates/
% svn up
svn: Working copy '.' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

However, running `svn cleanup` doesn't work, as we know.

```
% svn cleanup
svn: In directory '.'
svn: Error processing command 'modify-wcprop' in '.'
svn: 'spacer.gif' is not under version control
```

`spacer.gif` isn't the problem here… It just can't move past the previous error to the next file. So I deleted all of the files from the directory other than `.svn`, and removed the SVN log. This made cleanup work, so that I could check out and rename the offending file.

```
% rm *; rm -rf .svn/log; svn cleanup
% svn up Header_3_nobookmark.gif
A    Header_3_nobookmark.gif
Updated to revision 1087.
% svn mv Header_3_nobookmark.gif foo
A         foo
D         Header_3_nobookmark.gif
% svn up
A    spacer.gif
A    Header_3_noBookmark.gif
```

Following this, I was able to go back to the root directory of the project, and run `svn up` to check out the rest of it.

Answer (score 2):

(Before you try moving folders and doing a new checkout.)

Delete the folder the offending file(s) are in - yes, even the `.svn` folder, then 
do an `svn cleanup` on the very top / parent folder.

Comment: Closing apps can also help. Visual Studio, TSVNCache, and TortoiseSVN windows all might lock your files.

Answer (score 2):

Subclipse gets confused by Windows' truly diabolical locking behaviour. [Unlocker](http://unlocker.emptyloop.com/) is your friend. This can find locked files and forcibly release the locks.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same problem on Windows 7 64-bit.  I ran console as administrator and deleted the .svn directory from the problem directory (got an error about logs or something, but ignored it).  Then, in explorer, I deleted the problem directory which was no longer showing as under version control.  Then, I ran an update and things proceeded as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have similar problems I use rsync (NB: I use Linux or Mac OS X) to help out like so:

```
# Go to the parent directory
cd dir_above_borked

# Rename corrupted directory
mv borked_dir borked_dir.bak

# Checkout a fresh copy
svn checkout svn://... borked_dir

# Copy the modified files to the fresh checkout
# - test rsync
#   (possibly use -c to verify all content and show only actually changed files)
rsync -nav --exclude=.svn borked_dir.bak/ borked_dir/

# - If all ok, run rsync for real
#   (possibly using -c again, possibly not using -v)
rsync -av --exclude=.svn borked_dir.bak/ borked_dir/
```

That way you have a fresh checkout, but with the same working files.
For me this always works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

When I face this issue with TortoiseSVN (Windows), I go to [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and run the '*svn cleanup*' from there; it cleans up correctly for me, after which everything works from TortoiseSVN.

Comment: This also works with a cmd window.  I don't know why it works when Tortoise fails, but it sometimes does.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into that too lately. The trick for me was after selecting "Clean up", in the popup options dialog, check "Break Locks", and then "OK". It cleaned up successfully for me.

Comment: SVN does not have a popup dialog per se; maybe you are using Tortoise. The OP is using the command line client, hence your advise is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. After some searching on the Internet found the [below article](http://h3x.no/2010/12/04/svn-gives-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database-error). Then realized that I was logged as a user different from the user that I had used to setup SVN under, a permission issue basically.

Answer (score 1):

There are some very good suggestions in the previous answer, but if you are having an issue with TortoiseSVN on Windows (a good product, but ...) always fallback to the command line and do a simple "svn cleanup" first.

In many circumstances the Windows client will not run the cleanup command, but cleanup works fine using thing the SVN command line utility.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem where cleanup would fail.  Originally I was trying to commit some code, but it said:

> svn: E155004: There are unfinished work items in '/my/path/to/files'; run 'svn cleanup' first.

But when I tried to cleanup:

> svn: E155007: '/my/path/to/files' is not a working copy directory

In my case, it turns out that I had a revision conflict.  My svn folder contained `.mine`, `.r1`, and `.r2` files.  Once I resolved the conflict, the cleanup ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It might not apply in all situations, but when I recently encountered this problem my "fix" was to upgrade the Subversion package on my system. I had been running 1.4.something, and when I upgraded to the latest (1.6.6 in my case) the checkout worked.

(I did try re-downloading it, but a checkout to a clean directory always hung at the same spot.)

Answer (score 0):

Read-only locking sometimes happens on network drives with Windows. Try to disconnect and reconnect it again. Then cleanup and update.

Answer (score 0):

After going through most of the solutions that are cited here, I still was getting the error.

The issue was [case insensitive OS X](http://groups.google.com/group/google-code-hosting/browse_thread/thread/fa71ba7a03dd6f1d/3ca4c06b29b9b488?pli=1). Checking out a directory that has two files with the same name, but different capitalization causes an issue. For example, ApproximationTest.java and Approximationtest.java should not be in the same directory. As soon as we get rid of one of the file, the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I hit an issue where following an Update, SVN showed a folder as being conflicted. Strangely, this was only visible through the command line - TortoiseSVN thought it was all fine.

```
#>svn st
!       my_dir
!       my_dir\sub_dir
```

`svn cleanup`, `svn revert`, `svn update` and `svn resolve` were all unsuccessful at fixing this.

I eventually solved the problem as follows:

- Look in the .svn directory for "sub_dir"
- Use RC -> Properties to uncheck the 'read only' flag on the entries file
- Open the entries file and delete the line "unfinished ..." and the corresponding checksum
- Save, and re-enable the read-only flag
- Repeat for the my_dir directory

Following that, everything was fine.

Note I didn't have any local changes, so I don't know if you'd be at risk if you did. I didn't use the delete / update method suggested by others - I got into this state by trying that on the my_dir/sub_dir/sub_sub_dir directory (which started with the same symptoms) - so I didn't want to risk making things worse again!

Not quite on-topic, but maybe helpful if someone comes across this post as I did.

Answer (score 0):

I did `sudo chmod 777 -R .` to be able to change the permissions. Without `sudo`, it wouldn't work, giving me the same error as running other commands.

Now you can do `svn update` or whatever, without having to scrap your entire directory and recreating it. This is especially helpful, since your IDE or text editor may already have certain tabs open, or have syncing problems. You don't need to scrap and replace your working directory with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by copying some colleague's .svn directory into mine and then updating my working copy. It was a nice, quick and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answers here didn't help me, but before checking out the project again, I closed and opened Eclipse (Subversive is my SVN client) and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

While facing a similar issue, manual merge in the repository sync view helped to solve the issue.

One file name was conflicting with other and it clearly mentioned the issue. Renaming the newer file to a different name resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the file `svn-xxxxxxxx` from the `~\.svn\tmp` folder, where `xxxxxxxx` is a number.