# Unlocking SVN working copy with unversioned resources

Tags: svn

I have a repository which contains some unversioned directories and files. The server running svn was recently changed and since the checkout was done using the url svn://OLD-IP, I relocated my svn working copy, this time to the url svn://NEW-DOMAIN-NAME.

Now since there are some unversioned resources, the switch did not happen properly and the working copy got locked. A cleanup operation did not work either because of these unversioned resources.

I looked up in the net and found about svn ignore and tried that but to no use. I am unable to release all locks. Any ideas on solving the problem? Once I release the locks, I believe I can use svn ignore and carry on the relocate operation.

Comment: Related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158664/what-to-do-when-svn-cleanup-fails

Answer (score 7):

Check your `svn status` output and the legend for the letters at `svn help status`.

Quite often, the problem is that there is a file where svn expects a directory, or other kinds of similar confusion (the letters should tell you which it is). If there are any conflicts (`C`), solve them first. You can recover lost directories with `svn update`, and `svn revert` can often help too (if there is anything important on your working copy which is not in the repository, make a backup of the working copy first!).

After most of the confusion has been cleared, `svn cleanup` and `svn update`/`svn switch` (`update` is nothing more than a special case of `switch`) should start working again.

In the worst case, you can do another checkout and manually copy over any locally modified files.

Answer (score 4):

Just run `cleanup` command and then do `update`.

Comment: Original question: "A cleanup operation did not work either, because of these unversioned resources."

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. Rename the offending directory and rebuild it from SVN, then copy over the files you modified. May need to run cleanup in the parent directory