# SVN says I need to perform cleanup, but the cleanup fails

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, commit

**Duplicate:** [Working copy XXX locked and cleanup failed in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127932/svn-working-copy-xxx-locked-and-cleanup-failed)

When I try to commit:

```
Error: Working copy 'D:\Webs\Drupal 6' locked  
Error: Please execute the "Cleanup" command.
```

When I try to do a cleanup:

```
Cleanup failed to process the following paths:
D:\Webs\Drupal 6
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See also the question: [What to do when svn cleanup fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158664/what-to-do-when-svn-cleanup-fails)

Comment: I usually end up refreshing the project, cleanup, refresh, cleanup, and praying that it is okay. I don't get this in Eclipse any longer with subclipse, but used to get it a lot with subversive. Once I had to check out again and dump the old checkout. What version of svn is on the server?

Comment: @JeeBee Dude, you saved my life, thanks man, appreciate it.