# SVN code cleanup issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN and all of the sudden I get this error when doing anything:

```
svn: Working copy 'root\html_editor' locked; try performing 'cleanup'
```

When I peform code cleanup command, I get this error:

`Error performing cleanup for 'root\html_editor': svn: Error processing command 'committed' in 'root\html_editor'
svn: Error replacing text-base of 'index.php'
svn: Cannot read from 'root\html_editor\.svn\tmp\text-base\index.php.tmp': root\html_editor\.svn\tmp\text-base\index.php.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Can anyone guide me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

a) Move the affected subdirectory out of the working copy -- put it somewhere else so it becomes invisible to SVN

b) cd to the root of the working copy

c) svn cleanup as necessary

d) svn update, which will recreate a clean subdirectory, with all the correct permissions.

e) Manually merge any changes to the subdirectory's files from the previously moved version.  Do NOT copy back in any of the .svn control area.

f) svn diff to verify the manual merge

g) svn commit should now work, since the permissions have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Problems of this kind happen sometimes in tortoise svn. In the worst case you can check out a fresh copy to a new location and overwrite the files which have local changes. Could be faster than looking for a particular broken file.