# SVN cleanup causes "error processing command 'modify-wcprop'"

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I'm trying to checkout a large directory and part way through, the SVN server crashed. I've tried to perform a cleanup but every time it errors saying a file is not under version control.

```
root@mitydsp-dev:~/nvsp2# svn cleanup 
svn: In directory 'Platform/qt5/qtdeclarative'
svn: Error processing command 'modify-wcprop' in 'Platform/qt5/qtdeclarative'
svn: 'Platform/qt5/qtdeclarative/LICENSE.FDL' is not under version control
```

If I go into Platform/qt5/qtdeclarative there is no LICENSE.FDL file. I tried deleted the qtdeclarative folder but when I run again I just get the same error up one directory.

```
root@mitydsp-dev:~/nvsp2# svn cleanup 
svn: In directory 'Platform/qt5'
svn: Error processing command 'modify-wcprop' in 'Platform/qt5'
svn: 'Platform/qt5/build.sh' is not under version control
```

Again, there is no build.sh file. I've done this 5 times now and I can't recheck out the repository because it takes 5-6 hours and I've already retried that once today. Does anyone know whats causing this?

I should note checking in the repository browser these files do exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found my answer. If this ever happens to anyone else delete any log files in the .svn folders. Sometimes there will be logs with numbers (Log1, Log2, Log3) so delete those too.

Comment: This solution worked for me, and more precisely I needed to remove the log files in the .svn directory within the affected folder(s)

Answer (score 0):

If your cleanup shows that there is no lock , and if there exits lock file alongside the log file under .svn folder, deleting the lock and log file will help us to resolve the issue.